# Safari's autocomplete is breaking a input form

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a form on my site broken by Safari's autocomplete like this:
[image]

i have tried to disable autocomplete but doesn't affect.
Here's my `first_name` html input:

```
<div class="form-group" _v-3d7f6581="">
    <label class="control-label" _v-3d7f6581="">First Name*</label>
    <input name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" required="" autocomplete="off" _v-3d7f6581="">
    <small class="help-block" _v-3d7f6581="" style="display: none;"></small>
</div>
```

css:

```
.form-group input[type=text],
.form-group input[type=password],
.form-group input[type=number],
.form-group input[type=email],
.form-group select,
.form-group textarea {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Anyone have solution to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you asking how to disable auto-complete, or asking how to fix the issue at hand?

Comment: Sorry, just updated post. i'm asking for fix that issue.

Comment: So how exactly is this broken “by autocomplete”? You said you turned it off via HTML attribute, but the effect still shows. So does this show only after you selected values via autocomplete, but not if you had typed those values into the form fields manually?

Comment: Please provide your css

Comment: @CBroe yes sir.

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig updated sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the CSS of auto-completed inputs directly using webkit! When using this, make sure to check for cross-platform compatibility, as you mentioned that this issue is Safari specific. You may find it beneficial to use that to your advantage and only apply the changes to Safari.

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    text-size: 0.8em;
}
```

You can apply the same settings to all of your inputs by stringing together the CSS identifiers, classes, and  so on!

For more information on the use of webkit to edit auto-complete forms, [checkout this article here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/)!